# Parsing an HTML page using curl and xpath in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, curl, xpath, web-scraping

I need to parse this web page https://www.galliera.it/118 getting the numbers under the coloured bars.

This is my code (that doesn't work!!) ...

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $url = 'https://www.galliera.it/118';

    print "The url ... ".$url;
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';

    //#Set CURL parameters ...
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '');
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //print "Data ... ".$data;
    //echo '<br>';
    //echo '<br>';

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($data);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    // This is the xpath for a number under a bar ....
    // /html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[6]/span
    // How may I get it?
    // The following code doesn't work, it's only to show my goals ..

    $greenWaitingNumber = $xpath->query('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[6]/span');
    $theText = (string).$greenWaitingNumber;

    print "Data ... ".$theText;
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';

?>
```

Any suggestions / examples / alternatives?

Comment: "that doesn't work" can you be more specific? also `(string).$greenWaitingNumber` is bad syntax and you can't just echo a `DOMElement` like that (`SimpleXMLElement` can when using Simple XML)

Comment: You're right ... sorry. White page and the web console says "Error 500". I think that the problem is about the  ... $theText = (string).$greenWaitingNumber; ....  line nut I'm not so sure if the $xpath->query is right (note that I obtained the xpath using "Inspect element" interactive function in the borwser ...

Comment: your x-path is good for a specific value because of the index notation, but to get all of them you need something a bit more generic at the start.. `/html/body/div/div/div/div/ul/li[6]/span`

Comment: Ok, thanks .. so ... $greenWaitingNumber = $xpath->query('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[6]/span'); is correct I suppose ... How may I print the $greenWaitingNumber value in this case?

Comment: `$greenWaitingNumber = $xpath->query('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[6]/span'); $theText = $greenWaitingNumber[0]->nodeValue;` will give you "2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your php script that is mining request by you data in nicely sorted array, you can see the results of script and change the structure as you need it. Cheers!

```
$html = file_get_contents("https://www.galliera.it/118");

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DOMXPath($dom);

// find all divs class row
$rows = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' row ')]");

$data = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $groupName = $row->getElementsByTagName('h2')->item(0)->textContent;
    $data[$groupName] = array();

    // find all div class box
    $boxes = $finder->query("./*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' box ')]", $row);
    foreach ($boxes as $box) {
        $subgroupName = $box->getElementsByTagName('h3')->item(0)->textContent;
        $data[$groupName][$subgroupName] = array();

        $listItems = $box->getElementsByTagName('li');
        foreach ($listItems as $k => $li) {

            $class = $li->getAttribute('class');
            $text = $li->textContent;

            if (!strlen(trim($text))) {
                // this should be the graph bar so kip it
                continue;
            }

            // I see only integer numbers so I cast to int, otherwise you can change the type or event not cast it
            $data[$groupName][$subgroupName][] = array('type' => $class, 'value' => (int) $text);
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, true) . '</pre>';
```

and output is something like:

```
Array
(
    [SAN MARTINO - 15:30] => Array
        (
            [ATTESA: 22] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => rosso
                            [value] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => giallo
                            [value] => 12
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => verde
                            [value] => 7
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => bianco
                            [value] => 2
                        )

                )

            [VISITA: 45] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => rosso
                            [value] => 5
                        )
...
```

Answer (score 3):

This might help simplify your xpath statement for this specific instance.

This will find all `li` elements with a class attribute matching "verde" that has a `span` element under it.

the `//` notation means "match at any level in the document" so you don't have to build your query from root

```
/* @var $node DOMElement */
$greenWaitingNumber = $xpath->query('//li[@class="verde"]/span');
foreach( $greenWaitingNumber as $node )
{
  echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

*note this will not deal with `class="verde foo bar"`

---

If you're only interested in one particular value...

```
$greenWaitingNumber = $xpath->query('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[6]/spa‌​n');
$theText = $greenWaitingNumber[0]->nodeValue;
```

This will print "2"